# Alternating Page Breaks in \foreach

Tags: page-breaking, foreach

I have a a list on which I would like the page to break after every even numbered item.

How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,20}
 {\x \linebreak}   
 % I want to divide each \x by 2
 % If the remainder is 0 then insert \pagebreak, else nothing.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifodd\x\relax\else\pagebreak\fi`

Comment: I can't quite get that to work. Where should that code go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\ifodd\x\relax\else\pagebreak\fi
```